# Apache server running html code but not recognizing php code

Tags: php, linux, apache

I just started to learn php. I am using lubuntu and that's why I don't want to install xampp, wamp, or similar programs  because I have very limited resources.

I installed Apache server and php 7, which seems to be working fine because I can execute and visualize html code via localhost. The problem is when I run php code the web page shows blank. How can I fix this issue?

I have only one file on /var/www/html which is called index.php and can be visualize on localhost/index.php

php -v
php 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.10.1

apache2 -v 
Server version:  Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu)

The code I have on index.php is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <body>
        something
        <?php
           echo "hello world";
        ?>
      </body>
</html>
```

On localhost/index.php it only shows "something", which means apache server is running correctly and runs html code but I don't know why php doesn't run. If Instead I just run a file with php code like

```php
<? php
phpinfo();
?>
```

it only shows a blank page.

Comment: You can't have a space here <? php

Comment: @John.M Thanks, I just corrected the error but still not working.

Comment: You're missing libapache2-mod-php installation. Do $ sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php  and then restart apache server by doing $ sudo systemctl restart apache2

Answer (score 0):

If you see a blank page then normally something else is blowing up behind the scene. I suggest you check both Apache and PHP error logs. Normally you would find both in `/var/log/*`

It could very well be permission related or a module missing.